# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (line 19 (for i in password))

Tags: python, string

Heyyo! Thank you for coming here. So here's the problem:

```
import random
from keyboard import press
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

#Brute force 8 digits

Keyb = Controller()

password = 0

input()
time.sleep(5)

while True: 
    int(password)
    password = password + 1
    str(password) #<----- weird
    for i in password: #<---- where the program is showing the error
        a = a + 1
    b = 8 - a
    for i in range(b):
        str(password) + "0"

    Keyb.type(password)
    press('enter')
```

When I try to turn it into string... nothing happends... why? It is probably syntax. I'm not a good programmer...... lol....... ty for helping!!!!

Comment: The statements `int(password)`, `str(password`, and `str(password) + "0"` do absolutely nothing - they throw away the new value that they produced.  You'd have to assign that value to some variable (perhaps `password = int(password)` for example) for there to be any effect.

Comment: TY... now that i think about it yea your totally right... so dumb of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting

```py
password = 0
```

Therefore, it is of type `int` which cannot be iterated, and hence the error message.

To make this work, you need to convert `password` to a string before iterating it.

In other words, your `while` loop would need to look something like:

```py
while True:
    password = int(password)
    password += 1
    password = str(password)

    for i in password:
       a += 1  # <- a is not defined in your code

    b = 8 - a
    for i in range(b):
        password += "0"
```